# flex column that takes remaining space disapears (goes down), why?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a "weird" combination of flex columns.

The first has a fixed width and sticks to the top while scrolling down.
The second has only a max-width and is very tall.
The Third has flex: 1, to use the remaining space and also sticks to the top while scrolling down.

My problem is the 3rd one sometimes disapears (goes to the bottoom) depending on the size of the second one.

this is my simplified code:

```
.first {
 width: 250px;
}

.third {
  flex: 1;
}

.roundedBox {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}

.item-long {
 background: orchid;
 height: 200vh;
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="first sticky roundedBox">Some content</div>
  <div class="roundedBox item-long ">Lorem ipsum dolor </div>
  <div class="third sticky roundedBox">Somecontent</div>
</div>
```

The real code can be seen here https://github.com/sergiosaint/Finance and the live demo here https://amortizacoes.netlify.app/

this image shows the problem appearing https://i.stack.imgur.com/suMQb.jpg

Comment: May I ask why you use `flex-wrap: wrap;`? Do you need to wrap for different sizes?

Comment: without flex-wrap the colums will have all the same size. (I can solve that by wrapping them with an extra div) is that what is causing this issue?

Comment: What I mean is that you could use `flex-wrap: nowrap;` so that even if the second element increases in size, it doesn't force the third element to wrap. That's why I wanted to know if you needed to wrap it at some point.

Comment: that seems to have fixed it, so good I have a solution. I just dont understand why it decides to wrap sometimes if there is space? In the example I give in the gif there is plenty of space for the 3rd column, but it doesnt use it...

Comment: The `flex: 1` on the third element tells it to fill any remaining space, but it will also wrap to the next line if there is not enough space to accommodate it.